# ASMX Web Service throwing error on adding dll or the class project which was used to create that dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, dllimport

I have created a sample C# ASP .NET Web service  in Visual Stdio 2008. I am getting error

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID`
 with error code `80040154` 
while trying with project as reference.

And the error `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format` Could not able to load the assembly error while adding DLL as reference.

Edit : I am able to call the same dll in C# Console application project and access the functions in it. 
I am getting the error only while calling it in webservice project.

Following is the contents of my Service1.asmx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using COMClient;

namespace DLLWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetInfo()
        {
            COMClient.DLLCOMWrapper obj = new COMClient.DLLCOMWrapper();
            //String returnedInfo = obj.Info();
            return "hi";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a guess, without more information, your program is 64-bit and the dll containing the COM object is 32 bit, or the other way around. 64 bit programs can only use 64 bit dll's, and 32 bit programs can only use 32 bit dll's.

Comment: Both are 64 bits dlls

Comment: You're going to have to provide some detail. You don't even tell us whether you are using WCF or ASMX, on the client or the server. You show us no code at all. This question is likely to be closed quickly without those details.

Comment: What is the user account used for your web service's application pool?

Comment: @Hatjhie How to check that ?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Based on the code provided I'd say it's ASMX.

Comment: In my IIS on Windows 8.1
http://postimg.org/image/ivq9dd8mb/

Comment: @Hatjhie I only have DefaultAppPool there.

Comment: Ok, then highlight DefaultAppPool by clicking it with your mouse, then see on your right side, click "Advanced Settings", the pop up would be displayed. Find Identity column and post the value here. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: no code had been provided at the time I wrote my comment.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @Hatjhie Value for Identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: @JohnSaunders When I click New project and Web under Visual C# , I could see following options ASP.Net Web Application , ASP .Net Web Service Application , ASP .Net AJAX Server Control , ASP .Net AJAX Server Control Extender ,  ASP .Net server Control , WCF Service application . Which one should I choose here I selected the second option which is ` ASP .Net Web Service Application`

Comment: None of the above. Click "WCF".